# Error 1400 Invalid window handle

Tags: c++

I have code:

```
......
    g_hWnd = CreateWindow( L"Urok6WindowClass", L"TitleWindow", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance,
                           NULL );
    if( !g_hWnd )
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, nCmdShow );
```

All works fine. But if I add:

```
    LPTSTR tilte_old= L"Old title";
    int gettus = GetWindowText(g_hWnd, tilte_old, 100);
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    WCHAR szTest[10];
    swprintf_s(szTest, 10, L"%d", error); 
    MessageBox(NULL, szTest, L"TEST2", MB_OK);
```

MessageBox >> 1400

gettus >> ''

Why is this happening? Why windows handle is invalid?

Comment: Are you sure `GetWindowText` fails? You should never trust errors `GetLastError` unless you really know the last function returned an error. Check `gettus` first.

Comment: You'll probably want an actual array to hold your window's text, not a pointer to some string in read-only memory. `TCHAR tilte_old [100];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) of `GetWindowText` is an out parameter:

> lpString [out] 
>    Type: LPTSTR
>
> The buffer that will receive the text. If the string is as long or longer than the buffer, the string is truncated and terminated with a null character.

So you need to supply a buffer to be filled, not a pointer to a constant string (the third parameter indicates the maximum size of the buffer to avoid overflow)

Try:

```
const size_t BUFF_SIZE = 100;
TCHAR title_old[BUFF_SIZE];
int gettus = GetWindowText(g_hWnd, title_old, BUFF_SIZE);
```

Also, you only need to call `GetLastError` if `gettus` is 0 (`GetWindowText()` failed)