# GetWindowText() error 1400

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to get the current active window name with the code below :

```
    HWND winHandle = GetActiveWindow();
    wchar_t buffer[512] = L"";
    int getT = GetWindowText(winHandle, (LPTSTR) buffer, 511);
```

When used on the window of the program, I get the window name correctly, otherwise, I'm getting error 1400. What could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Just using the search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138626/error-1400-invalid-window-handle

Comment: Don't cast things to shove them in. Use the appropriate Unicode version instead.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I don't think this is the same problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom maybe yes or not... lets the user2831763 decide :P

Comment: I already seen this thread, but thanks anyway :) this was not the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1400 is `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This means an invalid HWND is being passed to GetWindowText.

Working backwards, this means `GetActiveWindow` didn't return a valid handle, probably NULL instead. According to a comment on the [documentation for `GetActiveWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this will happen when the active window doesn't belong to the current application or thread.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I forgot to check the value returned by GetActiveWindow.